# What is the lifecycle of an AngularJS Controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can someone please clarify what the lifecycle of an AngularJS controller is?

- Is a controller a singleton, or created / destroyed on demand?
- If the latter, what triggers the creation / destruction of the controller?

Consider the below example:

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demo')
  .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/home', {templateUrl: '/home.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl'})
      .when('/users',{templateUrl: '/users.html', controller: 'UsersCtrl'})
      .when('/users/:userId', {templateUrl: '/userEditor.html', controller: 'UserEditorCtrl'});
  });

demoApp.controller('UserEditorCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, UserResource) {
  $scope.user = UserResource.get({id: $routeParams.userId});
});
```

eg:

In the above example, when I navigate to `/users/1`,user 1 is loaded, and set to the `$scope`.

Then, when I navigate to `/users/2`, user 2 is loaded.  Is the same instance of `UserEditorCtrl` reused, or is a new instance created?

- If it's a new instance, what triggers the destruction of the first instance?
- If it's reused, how does this work?  (ie., the method to load the data appears to run on creation of the controller)

Answer (score 237, accepted):

Well, actually the question is what is the life cycle for a `ngView` controller.

Controllers are not singletons. Anyone can create a new controller and they are never auto-destroyed. The fact is that it's generally bound to the life cycle of its underlying scope. The controller is not automatically destroyed whenever its scope is destroyed. However, after destroying an underlying scope, its controller is useless (at least, by design, it should be).

Answering your specific question, a `ngView` directive (as well for `ngController` directive) will always [create a new controller and a new scope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngView.js#L201-L206) every time a navigation happens. And the [last scope is going to be destroyed](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/65f5e856a161e7c91b9ebde1360242dc704d0510/src/ngRoute/directive/ngView.js#L179) as well.

The life cycle "events" are quite simple. Your **"creation event"** is the construction of your controller itself. Just run your code. To know when it gets useless (**"destruction event"**), listen to scope `$destroy` event:

```js
$scope.$on('$destroy', function iVeBeenDismissed() {
  // say goodbye to your controller here
  // release resources, cancel request...
})
```

For `ngView` specifically, you are able to know when the content gets loaded through the scope event `$viewContentLoaded`:

```js
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function readyToTrick() {
  // say hello to your new content here
  // BUT NEVER TOUCHES THE DOM FROM A CONTROLLER
});
```

[Here is a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZddQ5W?p=preview) with a concept proof (open your console window).

Comment: Nowadays the code that destroys the $scope lives at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/65f5e856a161e7c91b9ebde1360242dc704d0510/src/ngRoute/directive/ngView.js#L179 . Very helpful, thanks!

Comment: viewContentLoaded only works if you use a timeout because it gets dispatched just before the template is loaded... the docs say the opposite, but they are refering to raw `template: "HTML STRING"` when it's a template file it gets loaded async like.