# Angular ui-router onEnter function not firing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Thanks to some great help from the SO community, I have a working angular SPA that uses multiple states/views using the [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) library. However I am getting a behavior that seems at odds with the `angular-ui-router` documentation.

From their docs about [onEnter](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#onenter-and-onexit-callbacks), I would expect that anytime I use `$state.go("home")`, the `onEnter()` event tied to that state's config object would kick off, yet I don't see it happen. Example:

```
/* myApp module */
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {

$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: "/",
    views: {
        'top': {
            url: "",
            template: '<div>top! {{topmsg}}</div>',
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.topmsg = "loaded top!";
                console.log("top ctrl!");
            },
            onEnter: function () {
                console.log("entered bottom state's onEnter function");
            }
        },
        'middle': {
            url: "",
            template: '<div>middle! {{middlemsg}}</div>',
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.middlemsg = "loaded middle!";
                console.log("middle ctrl!");
            },
            onEnter: function () {
                console.log("entered bottom state's onEnter function");
            }
        },
        'bottom': {
            url: "",
            template: '<div>bottom! {{bottommsg}}</div>',
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.bottommsg = "loaded bottom!";
                console.log("bottom ctrl!");
            },
            onEnter: function () {
                console.log("entered bottom state's onEnter function");
            }
        }
    },
    onEnter: function () {
        console.log("entered home state");
    }
  });
}])
.controller('MyAppCtrl', function ($scope, $state/*, $stateParams*/) {
    $scope.statename = $state.current.name;
    $scope.testmsg = "app scope working!";
    console.log("MyAppCtrl initialized!");
    $state.go("home");
});
```

As you can see from all the `onEnter()` calls in the state's config objects, my expectation was that when the home state loads, I would start to see a list of all the states/views they were hitting firing off their console messages. However, only the very first `entered home state` message is being logged, from the `home` state's `onEnter` event. Not a single other view's `onEnter` is being hit. Am I misreading the docs?

[Here is a long-awaited fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7tzXh/5/) to demonstrate. Just show the console in firebug/chrome devtools and you will see the lack of console output.

Any help would be great. I'm using angular 1.2 and ui-router 0.2.0. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be a lot easier to debug a working example (i.e. Plunkr).

Comment: @NateAbele Sorry it took so long, but a fiddle is available to anyone who is interested. Thanks!

Comment: You might also consider working with [$scope events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094940/what-is-the-lifecycle-of-an-angularjs-controller) instead of using the router one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Two things:

- The `onEnter` method applies to *states*, not *views*. You have in your definition one state and 3 views, and for some reason you've attempted to attach URLs to your views.
- In order for a state to be entered, it first has to be exited. (A) You never actually leave the `home` state (since you only have one state definition to begin with), so you can never re-enter it. (B) It appears that you're actually trying to create child states within `home`. Even if you fix your syntax, it still won't work, because when you enter the child state of a parent, by changing to a different child state within the same parent, you still never actually leave the parent state, hence no re-triggering of `onEnter`.

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
 $state.reload();
```

to trigger the updates in promise responses in my case to solve this. You can also do

```
$state.reload()
$state.go("statename")
```

that is how I solved it.

See here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#statereload