# Using Angular JS, what is the correct way to close a web socket connection upon route change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket

The question is fairly self explanatory.

If I open a web socket connection in an Angular JS via a controller, it will remain open after navigation (route change).

This is normal behaviour of course, but I was wondering what might be the "best practice" way to request the connection be closed upon navigation.

I could obviously hook in to the `$routeChange...` methods and broadcast to the controller. But am I missing something? Is there a better way?

Comment: If your controller dies because of the route-change you could try listening for a `$destroy` event on the controller's `$scope`?

Comment: @ivarni does the controller always die?

Comment: More on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094940/what-is-the-lifecycle-of-an-angularjs-controller

Comment: @ivarni ok thanks. So binding to `$scope.$on("$destroy")` would be the answer. Would you like to answer the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen for the `$destroy` event on your controller's `$scope` and clean up everything that needs cleaning up, in your case that would be closing the websocket connections.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(event) {
    ...
});
```

Some more background on the lifecycle of angular controllers can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16096598/957731).