# How to use controller to show and hide login link?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, logout

I am building a phone directory application, where I have made a Log in system. When user successfully logs in, the login button will hide. Maybe I am doing it in a wrong way.

```
//html code is
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" ng-controller="chklogin as a" ng-switch on="a.logedin" >
        <li class="active"><a href="#/Home">Home</a></li>
         <li ng-switch-default><a href="#/login" >Login {{a.logedin;}}</a></li>

         <li ng-switch-when="true"><a href="#/Dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
         <li ng-switch-when="true"><a href="#" ng-click="a.logout();">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>

//controller
myApp.controller("chklogin", function() {
this.logedin='false';
        $.ajax({
        url: "process/chklogin.php",
        type: "post"
        }).done(function(res) {

            if (res == 'true') {

            return this.logedin='true';
            }
            else
            {

        return this.logedin='false';
            }
        });

        this.logout= function(){
            $.ajax({
        url: "process/logout.php",
        type: "post"
        }).done(function(res) {

            window.location="#/login";
        });
        }
});
```

- Now tell me what am I doing wrong and what should I do?
- What should I learn for this and where I can find it?
- Tell me how the controller updates the view when it logs in or logs out.

Comment: Its not something difficult to do with Angular

    http://jsfiddle.net/sravkum/EhTZW/light/

(Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

Comment: Thanks for the example and i understand this but i need it in the controller when user login its should be hide through the controller

Comment: First, don't use $.ajax, use $http service instead. Second, do use this.loggedin=false; don't use 'false' string - its truthy - which will cause problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comments, basic `ng-show` or `ng-hide` shall do the trick. However, you need to have a firm grasp and strong foundation on how AngularJs works in order to have a proper login and logout page, with the correct functionality as well as proper UI logic presentation.

My suggestion is to use `service` or `factory` in AngularJs, to reduce code base as well as streamline the login process. There will be times you need to persist some user-information, and service or factory can really be handy for this kind of situation.

Before giving you a solution, let me first comment about your code and also answer the three questions stated.

1. **Get rid of jquery mentality while using AngularJs**

   This is one of the most crucial part when you first begin learning AngularJs. Like in your code example above, use `$http` requests instead of using `$.ajax`.
2. **You need to understand the life cycle of AngularJs' components**

   Understanding what is the life cycle of `$scope` i.e the glue between application controller and the view shall basically answer your question. Here are some good resources: [Angular scopes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope), [Lifcycle of controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16096598/2829204)
3. **Read up on Angular's factory and service**

   As mentioned above, factories and services are good tools to reduce code base. If you are asking for resources to learn AngularJs, then one of the good sites is actually the [Angular site](https://angularjs.org/) itself.

So here is a very [simple plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/i4Iyz94rbpioH3YtjQmQ?p=preview) which I have created for you, hopefully it will be able to give you some basic insights. Few things to note though:

- I used `ui.router` for the routing. Maybe biased here, but it's just too awesome. In the event you get confused in the plnkr, just treat that this is just `ngRoute` doing his work.
- The code in plnkr is obviously for illustration purposes and cannot be used in real work. Real applications maybe more complex. I didn't even write the login logic in the plnkr. But I see you are capable of doing it, since your did write something in your controller.

Conclusion / tldr: The main gist of code that will do the magic is

```
<div ng-show='isLoggedIn'>
  <!--content that you want to show after a user has logged in-->
</div>
```

where `isLoggedIn` shall be the expression evaluated based on some login logic; and of course, use `ng-hide` to do otherwise.

Comment: Hmm very i really like your answer and its very very help full for me. thanks