# How to handle $stateChangeSuccess event if multiple states have same controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I'm using a single controller in two states. If I navigate within these two states, and try to handle $stateChangeSuccess event, I'm facing an issue which is, in each state, the event is triggering twice.

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
        // some code...
    });
```

I know that this is a game of $scope, but how can I handle it. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be watching $stateChangeSuccess on the $rootScope like this instead:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess' function() {
    //code
};
```

If that's not the case, here is some good information about [controller scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094940/what-is-the-lifecycle-of-an-angularjs-controller). From that, you should be able to watch the two events: [$viewContentLoaded](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) and [$destroy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$destroy)

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log('Stuff loaded');
});
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  console.log('Destroyed');
})
```

From there you should be able to determine the scope issue.