# ui-router: Do controllers ever get destroyed after transitions?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router and am trying to detect when a controller belonging to a view that's being transitioned away from gets destroyed.

So I currently have a `destroy` listener like so:

```
$scope.$on('destroy', function(){
    mySpecialFunction();
});
```

However, when a state change occurs to a different view\controller, this destroy event never fires.

The state I am transitioning to, is a sibling state so I'm going from `myParent.childA` to `myParent.childB` (where childA has the destroy listener added).

If I was instead going from `myParent.childA` to `myParent.childA.child1` then this would make sense since childA still exists in the hierarchy.

Can someone help me understand why the scope still exists in this scenario please?

Comment: Possible duplicate, this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094940/what-is-the-lifecycle-of-an-angularjs-controller) should help

Comment: Ok thanks, I have taken a look, and I'm not sure there is anything there that will help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event name you want is `"$destroy"` not `"destroy"`

Try

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
    mySpecialFunction();
});
```

This should get triggered under the conditions mentioned in question

Comment: Well that was embarrassing! Thanks @charlietfl